# Last record per transaction

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to select the last record per sales order.

My query is simple in SQL Server management.

```
SELECT *    
FROM DOCSTATUS
```

The problem is that this database has tens of thousands of records, as it tracks all SO steps.

```
ID    SO    SL      Status        Reason      Attach    Name   Name       Systemdate
22  951581  3     Processed       Customer      NULL    NULL    BW  2016-12-05 13:33:27.857
23  951581  3     Submitted       Customer      NULL    NULL    BW  2016-17-05 13:33:27.997
24  947318  1        Hold         Customer      NULL    NULL    bw  2016-12-05 13:54:27.173
25  947318  1   Invoices Submit   Customer      NULL    NULL    bw  2016-13-05 13:54:27.300
26  947318  1        Ship         Customer      NULL    NULL    bw  2016-14-05 13:54:27.440
```

I would to see the most recent record per the SO

```
 ID    SO    SL       Status          Reason      Attach    Name   Name       Systemdate   
 23  951581  4       Submitted        Customer      NULL    NULL    BW  2016-17-05 13:33:27.997
 26  947318  1         Ship           Customer      NULL    NULL    bw  2016-14-05 13:54:27.440
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I'm not sure how that table has two `Name` columns, but one easy way to do this is with `ROW_NUMBER()`:

```
;WITH cte AS 
(
  SELECT *, 
    rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY SO ORDER BY Systemdate DESC)
  FROM dbo.DOCSTATUS
)
SELECT ID, SO, SL, Status, Reason, ..., Systemdate
FROM cte WHERE rn = 1;
```

Also [please always reference the schema](https://sqlblog.org/2019/09/12/bad-habits-to-kick-avoiding-the-schema-prefix), even if today everything is under `dbo`.

Comment: Thank you, Your query will help me not just in this example but many more.  Would you know how I can convert the date to be only YYYY-MM-DD, no to show the time, this way I can create a date filter in Power Bi?

Comment: By the way, there were no columns with the same name, I just had to shorten the names and forgot to make them unique.

Comment: `Systemdate = CONVERT(date, Systemdate)`

Comment: When I try the syntax I get no results at all

Comment: You need to put that in place of `Systemdate` in the query I already provided, e.g. `SELECT ID, SO, ..., Systemdate = CONVERT(date, Systemdate) FROM cte ...`

Comment: Perfect, thank you for taking the time, you are awesome.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can keep it this simple:

```
SELECT *
FROM DOCSTATUS
WHERE ID IN (SELECT MAX(ID)
             FROM DOCSTATUS
             GROUP BY SO)
```

You want only the maximum ID from each SO.

Comment: Yes, it should be an identity column which always increments and should have an index on it. Generally, ID is of type INT and should also be smaller than Systemdate and more likely to have an index.

Comment: Your question says "last record per sales order" - doesn't say "last updated record per sales order"

Answer (score 0):

An efficient method with the right index is a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.systemdate = (select max(t2.systemdate) from t t2 where t2.so = t.so);
```

The index is on `(so, systemdate)`.